# ASP.NET master pages- does the order of the contentplaceholders matter on the web content forms?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I want to rearrange my master page layout. The problem is, i already have dozens of web content forms created off of that master.

Namely- i want to create a Header contentplaceholder and Footer placeholder, and move my css and javascript loads to the header and footer respectively.

my question is- can i just place the contentplaceholder containers anywhere on the form, and things will render properly? does placing them out of order have any impact on performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will render just fine, as far as i have used I haven't notice any impact on performance.